# Cannot establish connection to embedded derby database Netbean

Tags: java, database, derby

The problem is that this connecting java application would not connect to my database. Please help, I don't know what is wrong with my code.

In my code there are Chinese because I am creating a database and jframe specifically for Chinese users. I am new to programming and creating this stuff, so please be patient and simple when explaining :)
Thank you so much!

I think when I run it, it is supposed to display information about of all the columns stored in my database.

This is my DBConnect Java application code:

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DBConnect {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AccountProgramDB";
    String user = "cys19821982";
    String pass= " chen88566222 ";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, user, pass );

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM SHENJIWAIZI1";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );

    while ( rs.next( ) ) {

    String 报告文号 = rs.getString("报告文号");
    String 被审计单位名称 = rs.getString("被审计单位名称");
    String 被审计单位类型 = rs.getString("被审计单位类型");
    String 审计年度 = rs.getString("审计年度");
    String 发票日期 = rs.getString("发票日期");
    String 报告日期 = rs.getString("报告日期");
    String 签字注册会计师 = rs.getString("签字注册会计师");
    String 意见类型 = rs.getString("意见类型");
    String 已审资产总额_元 = rs.getString("已审资产总额_元");
    String 已审营业收入_元 = rs.getString("已审营业收入_元");
    String 收费金额_元 = rs.getString("收费金额_元");
    String 备注 = rs.getString("备注");

    System.out.println( 报告文号 + " " + 被审计单位名称 + " " + 被审计单位类型 +" "+ 审计年度 +" "+ 发票日期 +" "+ 报告日期 +" "+ 签字注册会计师 +" "+ 意见类型 +" "+ 已审资产总额_元 +" "+ 已审营业收入_元 +" "+ 收费金额_元 +" "+ 备注 );
    }

   }
   catch ( SQLException err ) {
    System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }

}
```

}

[This is a screen shot of my database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzY1Y.png)

This is the error message:
Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Userid or password invalid.
Pretty sure I have the correct user and pass.

Comment: Probably you haven't register you driver. Try to add following line `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();`
before the line `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, user, pass );`

Comment: 1) *"Please Click here for the actual explanation"* No, I'm not following a link to an image that explains. Explain it in words.  2) Try to establish a connection to the DB in a command line app. with no GUI first. That way, it is not only simpler, but has *nothing to do with Swing.*

Comment: What happens when you run your program? Do you get an exception? Capture and display the **entire** exception in your question: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: This is the error message that I am getting:                                                     Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Userid or password invalid.                                                                                                                            Pretty sure I have the correct userid and password. I just changed it using the system utility command:                                                            call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY ('derby.user.CYS19821982', 'chen88566222')

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE PROBLEM!

The original line is: String pass= " chen88566222 ";

There are two spaces before and after the password, that's why it didn't work.....

String pass= "chen88566222";

Now this worked....

OMG, why am I so stupidddddd

So happy now bth!!